# How do I transform a pattern match to use Rust 2018's automatic borrowing?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, borrow-checker

Is there a way to transform the `match` statement in the following code to the simplified 2018 edition syntax with automatic borrows?

```
enum Entry {
    Dir { mtime: i64 },
    File { mtime: i64, _size: u64 },
}

fn touch(entry: &mut Entry, mtime: i64) {
    let x: &mut i64 = match *entry {
        Entry::Dir { ref mut mtime } => mtime,
        Entry::File { ref mut mtime, .. } => mtime,
    };
    *x = mtime;
}

fn main() {
    let mut entry1 = Entry::Dir { mtime: 0 };
    touch(&mut entry1, 1);

    let mut entry2 = Entry::File {
        mtime: 0,
        _size: 1024,
    };
    touch(&mut entry2, 1);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b3b27a0b95c147b1246d1ae2c62bffc6)

This is what I tried, but the lifetime of the references were limited to the end of the `match` statement.

```
let x: &mut i64 = match entry {
    Entry::Dir { mut mtime } => &mut mtime,
    Entry::File { mut mtime, .. } => &mut mtime,
};
```

```
error[E0597]: `mtime` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:8:37
   |
7  |     let x: &mut i64 = match entry {
   |         - borrow later stored here
8  |         Entry::Dir { mut mtime } => &mut mtime,
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
9  |         Entry::File { mut mtime, .. } => &mut mtime,
10 |     };
   |     - `mtime` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Comment: Remove every hint: `let x = match entry { Entry::Dir { mtime } | Entry::File { mtime, .. } => mtime };`

Comment: Fixed title. Fixed grammar. Answered in a comment. And THEN closed as duplicate. You are my hero, @Shepmaster for all the service you are doing for the Rust community